# Gatsby + Hotjar : Env variables for Hotjar-Id & Hotjar-Snippet Version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, hotjar

[here it says](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-hotjar/) that i need to set up hotjar like this, if i want to use it with gatsby:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-hotjar`,
    options: {
      id: YOUR_HOTJAR_ID,
      sv: YOUR_HOTJAR_SNIPPET_VERSION
    },
  },
]
```

My novice question now is: Can I just paste id / snippet version in there directly? Or do I have to worry about security issues and should go for environment variables etc?

Answer (score 3):

You can paste them in there directly.

The Hotjar instructions mention to add this snippet to the top of every page

```
<script>
    (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:99999999999999,hjsv:00000000000000};
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                          SITE ID             SNIPPET VERSION

        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
</script>
```

This plugin is doing the same thing, here: https://github.com/pavloko/gatsby-plugin-hotjar/blob/d30edfe1bf56b98feb819310d3a16d3d30118793/src/gatsby-ssr.js#L13

Either implementation is going to be viewable by anybody looking at the source of your website.